# In a NxN matrix, what algorithm finds the shortest path between two nodes?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

Being new to algorithms and having searched all over the web, including some answers on stackoverflow, I still find myself asking how I find the distance between those nodes in a simple matrix.

First of all, the simple matrix:

```
public class MatrixRoutes {

 int[][] position;   // matrix
 int size;  

 MatrixRoutes(int dimentions) {
  posicion = new int[dimentions][dimentions];
  size= dimensiones; 

   } 
}
```

I set the size of the matrix with a simple

```
 MatrixRoutes r = new MatrixRoutes(5);
```

Cool! I have my empty grid!

Populating it with the most simple of data, distances:

```
    r.position[0][1] = 1;
    r.position[1][1] = 0;
    r.position[0][2] = 2;
    r.position[2][2] = 0;
    r.position[0][3] = 3;
    r.position[3][3] = 0;
    r.position[0][4] = 4;
    r.position[4][4] = 0;
    r.position[0][5] = 5;
    r.position[5][5] = 0;
```

There's my test distance matrix, all ready to be tested.

Alright, got my nodes with distances. Now it's a matter of finding the shortest distance. I've been reading about different algorithms and their implementations with Java.

I've wanted to implement Dijkstra's algorithm, but it seems to only accept one starting number, used as a distance variable? That's not what I need when I need the distance between two variables.

Here's my attempt at implementing the algorithm:

```
private static int buscarRutaMasRapida(MatrixRoutes g, int nodeOrigin, int nodeDestiny) 
{
int[] found = new int[g.position.length];
boolean[] visitedNode = new boolean[g.position.length];
int max = 999;
for (int i = 0; i < g.position.length; i++)
{
    mejor[i] = max;
    visitedNode [i] = false;
}

found[nodeOrigin+ nodeDestiny] = nodeOrigin + nodeDestiny;

for(int i = 0; i < g.position.length; i++)
{
    int min = max;
    int nodoNow = nodeOrigin;
    for (int j = 0; j < g.position.length; j++)
    {
        if (!visitedNode [j] && found [j] < min)
        {
            nodoNow = j;
            min = found [j];
        }
    }
    visitedNode [nodoNow ] = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < g.position.length; j++)
    {
        if (g.position[nodoNow ][j] < max && found[nodoNow ] +   g.position[nodoNow ][j] < found [j])
        {
            found[j] = found [nodoNow ] + g.position[nodoNow ][j];
        }
    }
}
        return found [g.position.length - 2];
}
```

All I'm asking is someone who would know of an algorithm which would find the shortest distance between two nodes in either a normal adjacency matrix or distance matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dijkstra's is the (my) preferred route. It takes in one node and finds the shortest path to *all other nodes*. Usually for distance between two nodes one would create a check inside Dijkstra's to return when the desired "end" node is reached.

In fact, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm%20%22Wikipedia) has very nice psuedocode for you to use.

So for instance in the first step of Dijkstra's, you need to find the distance from the origin point S, you would look at all distances from S to other nodes and put this into your priority queue:

```
queue.add(position[S][x]); //Do this for all x adjacent to S
```

Comment: I think my issue is finding that distance between two nodes in the graph. I assume it's origin + distance, but that doesn't sound right if I take diagonals into account.

Comment: Ahh... in other words, if it's a NxN matrix, then the length of g.position should be enough?

Comment: It's NxN, initialized with [n][n] positions.

Comment: You don't need to use the length of g.position. You should just use the values stored inside it. Eventually your answer distance will be stored in g.position[nodeOrigin][nodeDestiny].

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store the distance between each point then repeated use of Dijstraka's algorithm is inefficient if the adjacency graph is dense.

Instead you want the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm).

From the wikipedia page, Dijstraka's will have a running time of `O(V E log V )` while Floyd-Warshall will be `O(V^3)`. In a connected graph `E` is between `V` (singly connected) and `V^2` (each node connected to every other node), so the best will really depend on your data.